# How to programmatically add the exact name of the field in the form?

Tags: entities, 10

I have used hook_entity_base_field_info in my custom module to add a field to the user entity:

```
$fields['phone'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('telephone')
  ->setName('phone')
  ->setLabel(t('Phone number'))
  ->setDescription(t('User phone number information.'))
  ->setRequired(TRUE)
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setTranslatable(FALSE)
  ->setSetting('max_length', 15)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'telephone_default',
    'weight' => -3,
    'settings' => [
      'placeholder' => '123-456-7890',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'type' => 'telephone_default',
    'weight' => -3,
    'label' => 'above',
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

But in the user form, the name of the field is name="phone[0][value]" as follows:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-phone-0-value" aria-describedby="edit-phone-0-value--description" type="tel" id="edit-phone-0-value" name="phone[0][value]" value="" size="30" maxlength="256" placeholder="123-456-7890" class="form-tel required form-element form-element--type-tel form-element--api-tel" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

I want my field name to be like name="phone" and id="edit-phone". How can i make my phone field name like email field:

```
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-mail" aria-describedby="edit-mail--description" type="email" id="edit-mail" name="mail" value="" size="60" maxlength="254" class="form-email required form-element form-element--type-email form-element--api-email" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

I also tried to create field in install yml file, but the result was the same.

Comment: You may have to use a different framework.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question compares the form element added for a *telephone* entity field with the form element used for the account email, and wonders why in the latest case the form element name is simply *mail*, I will answer this part.

The *Email address* form element is not added as entity field, but it is a normal form element added by [`AccountForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21AccountForm.php/function/AccountForm%3A%3Aform/9).

```php
  $form['account']['mail'] = [
    '#type' => 'email',
    '#title' => $this->t('Email address'),
    '#description' => $this->t('The email address is not made public. It will only be used if you need to be contacted about your account or for opted-in notifications.'),
    '#required' => !(!$account->getEmail() && $user->hasPermission('administer users')),
    '#default_value' => !$register ? $account->getEmail() : '',
  ];
```

If you add a new email entity field (for example, *Secondary email*), its HTML element name would be similar to the one you noticed for the telephone field.

```html
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-field-secondary-email-0-value" type="email" id="edit-field-secondary-email-0-value" name="field_secondary_email[0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="254" placeholder="" class="form-email form-element form-element--type-email form-element--api-email">
```

This does not happen just for the email form element, but also for the *Username* field, which is added from `AccountForm::form()` too.

```php
  $form['account']['name'] = [
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => $this->t('Username'),
    '#maxlength' => UserInterface::USERNAME_MAX_LENGTH,
    '#description' => $this->t("Several special characters are allowed, including space, period (.), hyphen (-), apostrophe ('), underscore (_), and the @ sign."),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'username',
      ],
      'autocorrect' => 'off',
      'autocapitalize' => 'off',
      'spellcheck' => 'false',
    ],
    '#default_value' => !$register ? $account->getAccountName() : '',
    '#access' => $account->name->access('edit'),
  ];
```

The HTML markup added for that form element is the following one, on Drupal 10.2.

```html
<input class="username form-text required form-element form-element--type-text form-element--api-textfield" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" data-drupal-selector="edit-name" aria-describedby="edit-name--description" type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="admin" size="60" maxlength="60" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

It could be possible to get a simpler HTML element name for a telephone entity field, by adding a form element that overrides the one used by the entity field, but only when the form element is added by an entity form class like the [`AccountForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21AccountForm.php/class/AccountForm/9) class. Anything added after, for example in a `hook_form_alter()`/`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` implementation, would not have any effect.